# Include a Ruby module but change the root module reference

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Given a Module `Foo`, I would like to extend this module, but **not** preserve the module name `Foo`.

```rb
# sscce (irb)
module Foo
  class Foo; end
end

module Bar
  include Foo
end

> Foo::Foo
Foo::Foo
> Bar.ancestors
[Bar, Foo]
> Bar::Foo
Foo::Foo
```

How can I get `Bar::Foo` to be `Bar::Foo` (not `Foo::Foo`) without redefining the class?

I've attempted `include` and `prepend` as well as `include Foo.clone` with the same result.  I think it's safe to assume that it's referencing the original class definition, fine, but I'd still like to have the `class Foo` actually belong to `Bar`.

Comment: The Class `Foo::Foo` does not belong to the Module `Foo` it is merely "lexically" encapsulated by `Foo`'s (Module) declaration and thus it's Class name, for reference, is generated accordingly as `Foo::Foo`. Following this your theoretical `Bar::Foo` class would not belong to `Bar`. Can you please explain *why* you would like this functionality

Comment: Exactly, so that is the crux of my question - How can i make it not merely "lexically" encapsulate the declaration.  Can I have the class belong to the module `Bar` somehow by including it, and if so, how?

Comment: You cannot have one class "belong" to another class. Ruby does not have nested classes.

Comment: Not belong to a class, but rather the `Bar` module.  So that it returns `Bar::Foo` rather than `Foo::Foo`

Comment: The real question I guess is why? `Bar::Foo` is `Foo::Foo` as you have shown. We are merely talking about constant references the same as if you put `module Bar; Baz = Foo::Foo;end`. If you truly want `Bar::Foo` to be its own Object reference aside from `Foo::Foo` but retain all of `Foo::Foo` you will have to inherit. We could hack this together by adding `def self.included(base); base.const_set(self.name,Class.new(Foo)); end` to the `Foo`(module) definition and then `Bar::Foo` will return `Bar::Foo` (a class that inherits from `Foo::Foo`) but again this leads back to *Why*?

Comment: `::Bar::Foo` and `::Foo::Foo` are the exact same class object. When you ask a class for its name, it will return the name of the first constant the class object was assigned, i.e. in your case `::Foo::Foo`. This name is immutable for a class after it was assigned once. To achieve what you want, you thus have to use different class objects.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this could work?

```rb
module Foo
  class Foo
    def foo
      puts "inside: #{self.class}"
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  class Foo < ::Foo::Foo; end
end
```

now when you do:

```rb
a = Foo::Foo.new
a.foo # inside: Foo::Foo
```

and if you do

```rb
b = Bar::Foo.new
b.foo # inside: Bar::Foo
```

instead of trying to include/extend `Foo` in a tricky way just create a new class inside the `Bar` module and rely on inheritance?

Comment: I think that `class Foo < ::Foo::Foo; end` would be redefining the class, which I would like to avoid doing since there could be thousands of classes within this module, and would have to redefine each.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a class belong to a module by inclusion. Even more - a class doesn't belong to a module even without inclusion (only a reference to a class is available as a module constant). When you import `Foo` to `Bar`, you *bring* there the constants and instance methods from `Foo`, that's why you have access to `Foo::Foo` by using the `Bar::Foo` constant and it points to the uniquely identified class `Foo::Foo`.

If you want to have the class `Bar::Foo`, it will be a different class uniquely identified by this "address". And if you want to have it identical to `Foo::Foo`, you'll have to use the `included` hook in module `Foo` and then do some heavy metaprogramming stuff to create a new class from the old one and assign it to a constant with the same name from the new module.

Or, maybe it could be enough just to clone the class:

```
module Foo
  class Foo; end

  def included(mod)
    mod.const_set('Foo', self::Foo.clone)
  end
end

module Bar
  include ::Foo
end

obj1 = Foo::Foo.new
obj2 = Bar::Foo.new
Foo::Foo == Bar::Foo  # false
```

But I'm not sure if cloning is enough for all the cases.